# HTML dropdown manipulated with JQuery not showing

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to update an HTML dropdown with JSON data from from Django backend.

When `console logged`, I can see the needed changes, but it doesn't reflect in the HTML document so I can select.

**HTML code:**

```
<div class="col-md-4">
   <div class="form-group">
       <label>Local Government </label>                                                                                                
       <select id="lga" class="listing-input hero__form-input  form-control custom-select">
           <option value="">Select an option</option>                                                                                                                                                                             
       </select>                                                    
   </div>
</div>
```

**Javascript Code:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("#id_form1-state").on("change", function() {
            var stateID = $("#id_form1-state")[0]['value'];                

            if(stateID){
                var selectBox = document.getElementById("lga");

                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: loadCitiesURL,
                    dataType: "JSON",
                    data: {
                        stateID: stateID,
                        csrfmiddlewaretoken: csrfToken
                    },
                    success: function(data){
                        $.each(JSON.parse(data), function(index, option){                               
                            selectBox[index] = new Option(option['fields']['name'], index, false, false)                                                                
                        });
                        console.log(selectBox);
                    }                                            
                });
            }
        });
    });
```

**Result page (Not displaying dropdown);**

[image]

**Update**
Added the response from the server:

```
[{"model": "properties.lga", "pk": 2, "fields": {"name": "Ikpoba-Okha"}}, {"model": "properties.lga", "pk": 1, "fields": {"name": "Oredo"}}]

# handled with JSON.parse
```

Comment: can you post the data returned by the ajax call also ? console it and post it here.

Comment: That drop-down looks like it might be the target of a plugin and not a standard native `<select>`.  If that's the case then you likely need to trigger the plugin to update as well.  A standard `<select>` appears to update just fine: https://jsfiddle.net/rb6tjeg8/

Comment: Hi David, could you explain further. I can see a plugin.js file. Be "trigger" do you mean disabling?

Comment: @kinGKong: That depends on what plugin you're using.  Some may watch the DOM for updates, some may not.  Some may expose a function to re-generate the plugin content from the DOM, some may expose a function for modifying elements and internally updates the DOM, some may need to be disabled and re-enabled, etc.  An a worthwhile exercise, see if you can create a runnable code snippet (using your data instead of the AJAX call) here in the question to replicate the issue.  If you can't replicate it, like I couldn't in my jsFiddle link, then the issue isn't present in the code shown.

Comment: Thanks @David I just tested that. The snippet in the JS fiddle link didn't work. I guess it has to do with the plugin.